# How to open sq-lite Database in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, android-sqlite

I am following this   [steps](http://www.tylerfrankenstein.com/user/4/browse-android-emulator-sqlite-database-eclipse)

But it can't display the db browser button visible..
that's why dp can't open

see the window

[image]

Please anyone tell me what can I do
Thank you...

Comment: `Navigate to: '/data/data/your.app.name/databases/my_db_name.db` - are you sure you put your db in the correct db path? Note the extension: **db**

Comment: in image there is my sqlite db which I wont to open which is in /data/data/your.app.name/myDBname.sqlite

Comment: ... which doesn't match the **correct path** and doesn't end in **db**, but in **sqlite** - Read my comment above mindfully.

Comment: can you plz tell me how to navigate . SQLite is new for me .how to give extension db

Comment: I told you where to put your db. I told you how your db should be named (at least, to use it with Questoid plugin, the db extension is needed - if I remember well it doesn't accept `.sqlite`): normally it's named: **yourAppName.db**. Then you select the db and click the icon... done

Comment: But In my '/data/data/your.app.name/' folder there is no any 'databases' folder . .Should  I create this folder ? but my sqlite db file is generated there is no any '.db' file is present in project and '/data/data/your.app.name/'

Comment: Yes, you should. If you create your db in your app, then it will be automatically created in that location. Rename your file into one that ends in "db". `my sqlite db file is generated there` - Is your app generating the db? so... you gave the path and the name ending in .sqlite - just remove the path and the extension from your code. You'll see that the db will be generated into the default path and with the default extension. It would be a good idea if you'd add your db helper class to your question.